# Cannot get media to play in wxpython

Tags: python, wxwidgets, wxpython

I just want to add a simple video to my application and I cannot get wx.media.MediaCtrl to work.
It seems to fail when I call Load(), I have checked to make sure the path exists ect.

```
import wx
import wx.media

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None)
        self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER, szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_QUICKTIME)
        self.media = '/Users/nicholasmaisel/Downloads/test.mp4'
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.quit)
        print(self.testMedia.Load('/Users/nicholasmaisel/Downloads/test.mp4'))
        if self.testMedia.Load(self.media):
            pass
            print("loaded")
        else:
            self.testMedia.Play()
            wx.media.MediaCtrl()

            print("Media not found")
            self.quit(None)

    def play(self, event):
        self.testMedia.Play()

    def quit(self, event):
        self.Destroy()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Frame = TestPanel()
    Frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
```

I just want to add a simple video to a panel in wx.python, if anyone could please help it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: _It seems to fail when I call Load()_ What happens?

Comment: when I print(self.testMedia.Load(*file*), it says false.

Comment: You are loading test.mmp4. Notice the double m !!!

Comment: Still, I guess it all depends on whether your backend supports the file format.

Comment: Try removing the `backend` parameter, let it make its own decision and change line 16 to `wx.media.MediaCtrl()` not `wx.media.mediaCtrl()`

Comment: Hey everyone, thanks for the responses! I fixed some of the errors but I am still receiving the same error.

Comment: Also, removing the backend part doesn't help either

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you check that you can play the media file with something else before you start. It sounds obvious but it can save ridiculous amounts of wasted time.
Here is your own code, adapted a bit, to allow me to get a screen shot.
Let us know, if it is still giving you grief, after running it, with a valid, tested, video.

```
import wx
import wx.media

class TestPanel(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, title='Media Player')
        self.testMedia = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
        self.media = '/home/rolf/27343023_69.mp4'
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_LOADED, self.play)
        self.testMedia.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_FINISHED, self.quit)
        self.Bind(wx.media.EVT_MEDIA_STOP, self.OnMediaStop, self.testMedia)
        self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.quit)
        if self.testMedia.Load(self.media):
            pass
        else:
            print("Media not found")
            self.quit(None)
        self.Show()

    def play(self, event):
        self.testMedia.Play()

    def quit(self, event):
        self.testMedia.Stop()
        self.Destroy()

    # Sets the mp4 file in a loop for testing only
    def OnMediaStop(self, event):
        self.testMedia.Seek(0)
        event.Veto()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = wx.App()
    Frame = TestPanel()
    app.MainLoop()
```

[image]

Comment: Hey, Rolf

Using your code on an mp4 file - I get an image from the video for only a splitsecond and then it hangs on a black screen. What gives?

EDIT: I tried the wmp10 backend - finally worked! nice, yet I had thought that the mediactrl would automatically pick it up which one would work

Comment: @VaidøtasI. What can I say, I don't know anything about your setup, os, video etc. What I can say, is it still works on my Linux box, wxpython 4.2, python3.8 two years later.

Comment: @VaidøtasI. I missed your edit. Glad to hear you got it working.